# How to make a STRUCT to keep track of some treeview and listview items?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, struct

I have a TreeView and 2 ListView in my program.

Please imagin the following picutre:

[image]

The first treeview is populated by some xml files. the text property of it is the filename (without ext) and its tag is the path to file.

If user clicks on any of the TreeNodes, the ListView on the middle will be filled with some data within the clicked xml file and if user clicks on them, the last ListView will also by filled by the data within that part of the xml file.

Now, my question is:
I already made a context menu for the last ListView so if user right clicks on an item, he/she can select that pin to add it to an ignor list. The problem is, I do not know how to make this ignor list, so if he/she goes to another file and do something else and when he/she comebacks to that TreeNode/ListView which he/she already added a "Pin" to ignor list (**Here everything will regenrate again**) that pin does not show in the list. (Note that I do not want to delete anything from the xml files!)

Please let me know if the question is not CLEAR!
[image]

Comment: My own idea is to make a List<string> and add to it something like "FilePath,GroupName,PinName" and each time user clicks a file name in the TreeView and data regenerates again, using string manipulation detect if the pin is already ignored or not! But I am really looking for a neat soloution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a class that can keep track of ignore information. Something along the lines of:

```
public struct PinInformation
{
     private readonly string testBatch;
     private readonly string vIGroup;

     public PinInformation(string testBatch, string vIGroup)
     {
          this.testBatch = testBatch;
          this.vIGroup = vIGroup;
     }

     public string TestBatch { get { return this.testBatch; } }
     public string VIGroup { get { return this.vIGroup; } }

     public override bool Equals(object o)
     {
          if (o == null) return false;

          PinInformation info = o as PinInformation;

          if (info == null)
          {
               return false;
          }
          else
          {
               return (this.testBatch == info.testBatch) && (this.vIGroup == info.vIGroup);
          } 

     }
}
```

You can then create a `Dictionary<PinInformation, List<string>>` object that keeps track of the elements that are ignored:

```
  var ignoreList = new Dictionary<PinInformation, List<string>>();
  ....
  void AddPinToIgnoreList(PinInformation info, string pin)
  {
        if (!ignoreList.ContainsKey(info)) //this is why we override Equals
        {
             ignoreList.Add(info, new List<string>());
        }

        ignoreList[info].Add(pin);
  }

  void RemovePinFromIgnoreList(PinInformation info, string pin)
  {
        ignoreList[info].Remove(pin);
  }
```

Now its simple to keep in sync the elements you are showing in your UI with the info stored in the ignore tracking system we've created.

Answer (score 0):

Create something like this, or what ever fit your needs:

```
public class IgnoreList
{
 private List<Group> groupsToIgnore = null;
 public List<Group> GroupsToIgnore
 {
   get{return groupsToIgnore;}
 }

 private List<Pin> pinsToIgnore = null;
 public List<Pin> PinsToIgnore
 {
   get{return pinsToIgnore;}
 }

 public IgnoreList()
 {
  groupsToIgnore = new List<Group>();
  pinsToIgnore = new List<Pin>();
 }
}
```

Now you can add one instance of this class to every TreeViewNode as Tag property to hold ignore list for that node.
Handle selected node change event and perform ignore list filtering.